# How do we conclude that following two groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H= \Bbb Z  \times \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ and $T = \{0\} \times \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$

Then $H/T $ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$

$\Bbb Z$ denotes integers, and $\times$ Cartesian product.

How did we make that conclusion? I come across such examples very often, could you give me some tips in order to see such I believe "triviality"?

Comment: My first thought would be to look for a surjective homomorphism $\phi : H \to \mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $T$.

Comment: In any product of groups, projecting down to a coordinate is a homomorphism. From there, first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Also, you could drop the second cartesian product. Just let $H=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and $T=\{ 0 \} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general fact is this:

> Let $H_i$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G_i$ $\;(i\in I)$. Then $ \prod_{i\in I} H_i $ is a normal subgroup of $ \prod_{i\in I} G_i $, and
>   $$ \Bigl(\prod_{i\in I} G_i\Bigr)\Big/\Bigl(\prod_{i\in I} H_i\Bigr)\simeq \prod_{i\in I}G_i/H_i.$$

Answer (score 2):

Define a map $\phi:H \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(m,n,0) \mapsto m$. It is easily verified that this is a group homomorphism, and that the image of $\phi$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover note that $\ker{\phi} = T$. Therefore, by the First Isomorphism theorem we have that:

$$
H/T \cong \text{Im}{\phi} = \mathbb{Z}
$$

Comment: I would have submitted the same answer. The idea comes from the fact that  you're using a direct product, and in a direct product, each of the groups is normal in the product itself, due to trivial conjugation, and so you can define maps like @wgrenard did. More generally these maps are called canonical projections, where the homomorphisms map your product to the groups you used to build your product in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The *trick* is you can just *divide*, so $\Bbb Z / \{0\}$ becomes $\Bbb Z$ and so on, and $\Bbb Z \times \{0\} \times \{0\} \simeq \Bbb Z$. A formal proof would be along these lines:

$(a, b, 0) - (c, d, 0) = (0, e, 0) \iff a = c$, so the cosets would be of the form $\{a\} \times \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ for each $a \in \Bbb Z$, so the quotient is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$